# How to set Word wrap in label in Xamarin Android (native)?

Tags: android, label, treeview, native, word-wrap

I have tried the below code for wrap the text inside the treeview in native android. But it doesn't work. Have anyone know how to wrap the text in label.

```
        android:ellipsize="end" 
        android:width="0dip" 
        android:maxLines="2"
```

could you please tell me how to wrap the text?

Answer (score 0):

This line of code seems to be wrong:

```
android:width="0dip"
```

Maybe you wanted to fix the width using the `layout_width` attribute.
Instead of

```
android:ellipsize="end" 
android:width="0dip" 
android:maxLines="2"
```

do this

```
android:ellipsize="end" 
android:layout_width="0dip" 
android:maxLines="2"
```